# Visual C++: Linking a DLL from another DLL using a relative path

Tags: c++, windows

I have the following file structure

```
C:\Application\application.exe
C:\Application\plugins\myplugin\myplugin.dll
C:\Application\plugins\myplugin\libs\utils.dll
```

Here `application.exe` loads `myplugin.dll` dynamically via `LoadLibrary`. Note that I have no control over `application.exe` as I am developing the plugin only.

What I want is to make `myplugin.dll` load `libs\utils.dll` via a ***relative*** path (ideally using static linking). That is, I don't want to be dependent on the location of `application.exe`. I currently add `C:\Application\plugins\myplugin\libs` to the `PATH` environment variable when installing `myplugin`, but environment variables are not an ideal solution and I want to avoid doing that.

I was hoping I could use assemblies and config files to specify the relative path `libs\utils.dll` in `myplugin.dll`. And I tried this, but to no avail. I then saw someone mentioning here on StackOverflow that config files only work for applications (i.e. executables). But as I said above, I have no control over `application.exe`. Is there a solution to this seemingly simple problem which I believe on Unix systems can be solved via rpaths?

Comment: No.  You must use GetModuleFileName() to discover your install location.  Append the subdir + filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot statically link to a DLL path at all, relative or absolute.  The PE imports table only contains filenames.  That is why a [DLL search path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) exists to locate DLLs.

If you want to control where `utils.dll` is loaded from, you have to load it dynamically.  `myplugin.dll` can retrieve its own path using `GetModuleFileName()`, using the module handle that is passed in to its `DllMain()` entry point.  It can then remove the filename from the path, append the relative path to the path, and then load the DLL when needed (not inside of `DllMain()` itself, or else a deadlock/crash may occur).

There are two ways you can handle this:

1. load everything dynamically yourself:

   ```
   #include <windows.h> 
   #include <shlwapi.h> 

   #pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

   HINSTANCE hThisDLL = NULL;
   HMODULE hUtils = NULL;

   typedef ReturnType __CallingConv (*DllFuncType)(Params);
   DllFuncType DllFunc = NULL;

   BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
   {
       if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
       {
           hThisDLL = hinstDLL;
           ...
       }

       return TRUE;
   }

   ...

   ReturnType CallDllFunc(Params)
   {
       if (!hUtils)
       {
           TCHAR szUtilsFileName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
           GetModuleFileName(hThisDLL, szUtilsFileName, MAX_PATH);

           if (!PathRemoveFileSpec(szUtilsFileName))
           {
               // do something...
               return ...;
           }

           if (!PathAppend(szUtilsFileName, TEXT("libs\\utils.dll")))
           {
               // do something...
               return ...;
           }

           hUtils = LoadLibrary(szUtilsFileName);
           if (!hUtils)
           {
               // do something...
               return ...;
           }
       }

       if (!DllFunc)
       {
           DllFunc = (DllFuncType) GetProcAddress(hUtils, "DllFuncName");
           if (!DllFunc)
           {
               // do something...
               return ...;
           }
       }

       return DllFunc(Params);
   }
   ```
2. static link to everything like you normally would, but then utilize your compiler's [**delay load**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) feature (if supported) so you can specify the DLL's filename dynamically at runtime, but still statically link to the DLL function itself (the delay-load mechanism will call `GetProcAddress()` for you).

   ```
   #include <windows.h> 
   #include <shlwapi.h> 
   #include <delayimp.h>

   #pragma comment(lib, "Delayimp.lib")
   #pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

   HINSTANCE hThisDLL = NULL;

   FARPROC WINAPI DelayLoadHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli)
   {
       if ((dliNotify == dliNotePreLoadLibrary) &&
           (strcmpi(pdli->szDll, "utils.dll") == 0))
       {
           TCHAR szUtilsFileName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
           GetModuleFileName(hThisDLL, szUtilsFileName, MAX_PATH);

           if (!PathRemoveFileSpec(szUtilsFileName))
           {
               // do something...
               return NULL;
           }

           if (!PathAppend(szUtilsFileName, TEXT("libs\\utils.dll")))
           {
               // do something...
               return NULL;
           }

           HMODULE hUtils = LoadLibrary(szUtilsFileName);
           return reinterpret_cast<FARPROC>(hUtils);
       }

       return NULL;
   }

   PfnDliHook __pfnDliNotifyHook2 = DelayLoadHook;

   BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
   {
       if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
       {
           hThisDLL = hinstDLL;
           ...
       }

       return TRUE;
   }

   ...

   ReturnType CallDllFunc(Params)
   {
       return DllFuncName(Params);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Remy, the delayed loading solves my problem! It's more complicated than rpath on Unix, but it's ok. By the way, instead of keeping a handle to the current module in a global variable, it's possible to obtain this handle inside the `DelayLoadHook` function like this:


`HMODULE hThisDLL = NULL;
GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (LPCTSTR) DelayLoadHook, &hThisDLL);` This way one doesn't necessarily have to implement the `DllMain` function.

Comment: @IliyanGeorgiev: Perhaps, but I would expect that to be slower, since it would have to validate the memory address and find the corresponding module, whereas `DllMain()` already gives you the module handle directly.

Comment: I agree, it's probably slower, though this code is executed only once, correct?

Comment: @IliyanGeorgiev: Yes, when any exported function from the DLL is called at runtime for the first time (unless you unload the delay-loaded DLL and then call an exported function again so it has to re-load the DLL again).